# TSQL: how to define efficient index on partitioned panel-data table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, index

The underlying table `piddt` is a panel-data structure containing three fields: `(pid, dt, attribs)`. The defined primary key is `(pid, dt)`.

The number of rows is around 6 Billion, and the table is partitioned by `dt` (which is month) into around 350 segments. Also table `pid` stores all unique pids with index defined (a single field).

I would like to extract the first record of each `pid`, and below is the query:

```
SELECT [first].*
FROM pid
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 pid, dt, attribs
    FROM piddt
    WHERE pid = pid.pid
    ORDER BY dt
    ) AS [first];
```

It runs very slow (taking 5-6 hours), and my suspicion is that it does not take advantage of the index and table partition.

Another query is tried as well, and it is just as slow:

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY pid ORDER BY dt) AS rowid
    FROM piddt
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rowid = 1;
```

My question is bit generic:

- what is the best practice to handle such panel data?

The above is actually a common construction. I searched yet didn't find a good solution for now.

Comment: I suspect you're running into a nasty sort on the dt column. Any chance of seeing the query plans?

Comment: What is your SQL server version? Your primary key should be the same as partitioning key and be of one column only...

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I just applied to get SHOWPLAN permission: you might laugh at me, :). Will report back once having the plan.

Comment: @Stoleg The SQL server version is 12.0 with SP1 (SQL Server 2014). The primary key is (pid, dt) which is different from the partitioning key. I agree it is an issue. Yet, all my search results show it is also how most people set up such panel-data tables.

Comment: The only advantage it can take from partitioning is if partitions are located on different physical drives, because you query touched all partitions. You should have approx 150-200 million unique `PIDs`. It will take time to extract. what is datatype of `attrib` column?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question: what do you mean by "handle"? Is it about storage or querying or using with application of some kind? What are your most common queries and use cases?

Comment: @Stoleg The `attribs` is a placeholder: the dataset I am working on has around 25 of such attribute columns -- they could be anything. The `handle` here just meant "process", "take good care of": no particular special meaning. The most common use case is to process the panel history for each `pid`. The biggest issue I felt so far is that the index structure does not allow me to track history efficiently. The above query is just one example.

Comment: Every use case will have an optimal setup. Therefore understanding main use cases will allow to tell the best way to handle data. If your main use is to track PID history, Do you need extracting 200mn rows (all distinct PIDs) on regular basis?